# Как парсить элементы HTML кода, если у них одинаковые названия?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Например, есть код:

```
1. div class = 'chtoto'
2. div class = 'chtoto'
```

У них одинаковые названия, и получу я только содержимое того элемента, который был раньше. Как получить данные из 2 choto?

Comment: `choto` у вас нету а есть `chtoto` я в python НОЛЬ но просто вижу что нету `choto`

Comment: используйте `find_all`, он вернёт список найденых элементов

Comment: какой яп вашего кода?..

Answer (score 1):

Используйте метод `select` или `find_all`, чтобы вернуть список элементов, а у этого списка обращайтесь к нужному элементу

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class='chtoto'>1</div>
<div class='chtoto'>2</div>
"""
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = root.select('.chtoto')[1]
print(tag.text)
# 2
```

**Второй вариант**, использование псевдокласса [nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) для css-селектора, тогда можно обращаться к одному элементу через `select_one`:

```
tag = root.select_one('.chtoto:nth-of-type(2)')
print(tag.text)
# 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Если пути разные, то можно попробовать реализовать через xpath, но с beautiful-soup пока не работал, - есть ли возможность такая не могу знать. Работу с xpath можно реализовать через Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть несколько одинаковых элементов с одинаковыми тегами, классами и т.д. то вы можете использовать дополнительный аргумент beautifulsoup для поиска по шаблону строки с помощью регулярных выражений `re`. Например если текст в первом элементе abcdefg, а во втором 1234567 то обратиться именно ко второму элементу вы можете следующим образом:

```
html=requests.get('url')
soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text, lxml)
x=soup.find('teg', class_="class", string=re.compile('[0-9]+'))
```